# Dell Inspiron R15 3521 BIOS doesn't show the option to boot from USB

Tags: ubuntu, usb, bios, dell-inspiron

Secure Boot is disabled and I'm on Legacy Boot right now.

When I go to Boot settings there doesn't seem to be any option to boot from USB or even add that as an option. (I have tried two USB 2.0 and two USB 3.0 ports! The USB is detected and works fine on all ports when I copy files and stuff.)

I've created the live USB using the `Startup Disk Creator` that comes with Ubuntu 14 as well as `unetbootin`!

The USB has a total capacity of 16 GB (in case it matters)! No other device is connected to the laptop.

[This article](https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive) talks about a "settings tab" in the boot menu for my laptop's model, but that is not available here.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 right now; is there a way to start the installation process from the existing OS?

Screeshots from the BIOS menu:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to enable "USB emulation" in "Advance": h

[image]

Comment: You might need to reboot and re-enter BIOS after changing that setting and the respective Boot mode.