# Booting Windows 10 installation off a USB does not work only on one of my laptops

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-installation, bootable-media

I used Unetbootin and gparted to burn a Windows 10 media creation tool on my Linux machine to a NTFS file system bootable USB. Everything is working perfectly on two machines, but on one of my laptops, nothing I have tried helped me remove the black screen and blinking cursor whenever I try to boot the installation USB to that machine.

The laptop is a Dell Latitude 3521 if that helps, I disabled secure boot, tried with UEFI and not, I manually booted it, I changed the order, I tried finding options that might block this, I removed the USB and tried every other slot, the device shows on most of them though, I reset the bios. Nothing. The other machine and laptop only needed a simple boot from a USB selection and everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: Not every BIOS has pre-installed USB drivers.

Comment: @ThePirateBay What drivers to be exact, everything ever worked fine?

Comment: Note that I have a blinking underscore when I try to boot up from usb.

Answer (score 1):

Disable fast boot, go to bios by tapping f2 when start up and change the option to bootable usb.

Your installation media must be plugged in BEFORE turning the machine on. Also, enable "USB emulation" in "Advance".

Look at this case :

[Dell Inspiron R15 3521 BIOS doesn't show the option to boot from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/1037088/dell-inspiron-r15-3521-bios-doesnt-show-the-option-to-boot-from-usb)

Comment: I did all of that. Still nothing.